# How do I restart a MySQL local instance in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, startup

I've recently gotten into databases for a class I'm currently in, and I need a little bit of help. I've managed to create a database, and even populate a table with data which I was then able to grab from a node.js project I've made in Atom. Wonderful! When I went to shut it down, all seemed normal but now it won't restart. As in, when I'm in the homepage section of MySQL I double click the local instance I made(I can only assume this is opening the connection to the local instance where my database is stored) but it won't start up. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is an image of the error I'm getting. I can only assume it's because the actual server isn't on but I don't know how to turn it on. 
Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you!
 [image]

Comment: try running `mysqld` in command prompt

Comment: Error says it all. MySQL Workbench is not a MYSQL server itself. You have to have Server running in your system in order to Workbench connect to it.

Comment: If on windows go to services and start the service.

Comment: I wasn't turning on the actual server and that was definitely the issue! Thank you for your help, as that totally solved my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

As according to the users ikiK, P.Salmon, and Y4glory the issue I was having was that I wasn't actually turning on the server. I was able to do so by going through my Window's Services application, finding the MySQL server and starting it there instead of trying to do so through the workbench. 
Once again, thank you to those who commented as that was really helpful!!

Comment: I am facing the same issue and have tried starting through Window's services and also through commandline as described in other posts, but the service has not started. Have you applied any other ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every other way mentioned here and other related posts, but it did not solve my problem, the service just wont start, but the below approach with the ***mysql-installer*** did.

For this to work you need to have your installer which you have used earlier to install MySql.

1. Start your windows mysql installer. For me it was "mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0"
2. Then remove/uninstall the SQL Server and remove all configurations
3. Manually delete the SQL Server folder from "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0."
4. Start your mysql installer again and install the SQL Server again

You can check now that the MySqL Server has started.

Hope it helps someone.